# What is the worker process for IIS7?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-7

I'm trying to do 'Attach to Process' for debugging in Visual Studio 2008 and I can't figure out what process to attach to.  Help.

Answer (score 49):

Indeed it is still w3wp.exe - You'll need to check the '**Show processes in all sessions**' option to get it to show up though.

(It caught me out for a while too.)

Comment: +1 more for the checkbox tip.  A lot of times these posts assume settings.  Thank you for adding onto the above post.

Comment: I strongly recommend this as answer. Thanks Overflow

Answer (score 12):

Isn't it w3wp.exe?

Comment: As an aside, I'm going to have to move to vista on my work pc to use IIS7.  Fun fun fun.  It only takes about two days to install everything.

Answer (score 11):

[Here's a useful article](http://abhijitjana.net/2010/07/15/identifying-worker-process-w3wp-exe-iis-6-0-and-iis-7-0-for-debugging-asp-net-application/) for identifying w3wp processes, if you're running more than one.

> For IIS 6.0
>
> - Start > Run > Cmd
> - Go To Windows > System32
> - Run `cscript iisapp.vbs`
> - You will get the list of Running Worker ProcessID and the Application Pool Name.
>
> From IIS 7.0 you need you to run IIS Command Tool ( appcmd ) .
>
> - Start > Run > Cmd
> - Go To Windows > System32 > Inetsrv
> - Run `appcmd list wp`

Comment: Had more than one - this definitely helped.