# Why isn't w3wp.exe seen in taskmgr when running a web service?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, visual-studio-2012

I have two web services running in IIS 7 (on Windows 7). I need to attach to one of these services to debug using VS 2012. But when I choose *Attach To Process* in Visual Studio, there is no `w3wp.exe` process to attach to (even if I select to *Show processes from all users*).

TaskMgr also shows no `w3wp.exe`.

What is running the service then?  I know it's running because I see relevant errors in my browser.

[image: my image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the worker process for IIS7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60918/what-is-the-worker-process-for-iis7)

Comment: And if you launch Visual Studio as administrator ?

Comment: it's not a duplicate question in that i know what the process im looking for it but it's not there.

Comment: have you read the answer to the linked question? Particularly, the part about `Show processes in all sessions` setting?

Comment: i think so.  i indicated in the question that i selected to show procs from all users which is the phrasing in VS2012. The question you refer to is using VS2008.  So i still dont see w3wp.exe.

Comment: all users is not the same as all sessions, and you haven't mentioned which version of VS you use.

Comment: i am using VS2012 Professional. Where can i find the All Sessions option. I only see All Users. Thanks.

Comment: I have only 2008 and 2010 installed, and there the option is on the dialog together with 'all users' option.

Comment: image attached. please remove your close vote as it is incorrect and prevents others from participating here. thanks.

Comment: are you running as Admin? on which Windows version are you running?

Comment: also, it seems that managed code debugging is not enabled in your settings, only native code. You should check 'Managed code' too

Answer (score 1):

This sounds awfully like your web service is running under either the built-in "Cassini" web server (`WebDev.WebServer40.EXE`) or IIS Express (`iisexpress.exe`).

If this isn't the case then it sounds like the "full fat" IIS7 worker process for the web service in question has shut down due to its idle timeout.

Finally if you need to attach to an IIS7 worker process you need to launch Visual Studio as an administrator, i.e. right click on the VS icon on your start menu and choose "Run as Administrator".